# Caching paged LINQ results without using Skip() or Take()

Tags: sql-server, linq, paging, sqlcachedependency

I am using LINQ for paging data in my website. I am currently using Skip() and Take() to perform the paging. Now I want to cache the data using cache dependencies so that the the cache will invalidate if the data changes. However SQL Server's [query notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx) don't support the TOP expression. Are there any alternative ways to query a paged set of data with LINQ that doesn't generate TOP? Or another way to cache this data so that it invalidates?

Comment: How do you mix Linq and SqlDependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull your data in two passes:

```
// step1: get the IDs of the items in the current page.
List<int> customerIds = db.Customers
  .Where(filter)
  .OrderBy(c => c.FirstName)
  .ThenBy(c => c.CustomerID)
  .Select(c => c.CustomerID)
  .Skip(200)
  .Take(20)
  .ToList();

// step2: get the items for that page
List<Customer> customers = db.Customers
  .Where(c => customerIds.Contains(c.CustomerID))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: I like this idea! It will invalidate when a customer on that page is deleted or edited. However if you add a new customer and it changes the results in this list, I don't think a dependency based on the second query will be invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

Cache the entire result set, and set the SqlDependancy to that.

Read the entire set from the cache, and then use Skip/Take on that.

Comment: This is a good solution but unfortunately doesn't work for me because the data set would be too large to cache in memory.